# Custom view is measured incorrectly when placed with another view elements

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a custom view which I want to place in RelativeLayout with a button under it. The problem I'm having is that if I put a button under the custom view using android:layout_below="@id/customView", the customView takes full height, so there's no space on the screen to place the button, it's only placed below the bottom border of the screen and therefore invisible. The size I receive at the last call of customView's onMeasure() method should be already calculated, i.e. all another view sizes should be taken into account, but it seems that in this case height of the button is not.

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/darkBlueBackground"
tools:context="com.example.TimePickerActivity">

<com.example.TimePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/picker"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/picker"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

This is final sizes that were measured by onMeasure():

`07-26 00:24:39.551 19930-19930/com.example D/TAG: width = 720 height = 1230`

At the same time if I put the button above the customView everything looks pretty fine, onMeasure() receives correct height for the customView, so there's some space for button.

Here's layout for that case:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/okButton"
    android:text="OK"/>

<com.example.TimePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/okButton"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/picker"/>
```

Final size from onMeasure is different:
`07-26 00:24:39.551 19930-19930/com.example D/TAG: width = 720 height = 1134`

Why is the custom view (TimePicker) measured correctly in one case and isn't in another?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:layout_height=wrap_content"` on the `com.example.TimePicker` view. Setting the height to `match_parent` causes the view to fill the parent's height, leaving no room for the button.

Comment: Any reason you have a `layout_weight="1"` attribute on your button? That's more relevant to a linear layout. If you just have two vertically stacked items, a vertical LinearLayout would work the same.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have LinearLayout with two buttons instead of just one button (which is still not working even without `layout_weight`).

Comment: Use of layout weight requires that one of the properties (height or width, depending on the orientation of your linear layout) is set to 0dp. For example, if you have a horizontal linear layout in which you want each button to take half set, each to have `layout_height="wrap_content" layout_width="0dp" layout_weight="1"`. If the linear layout is vertical, then weight is applied vertically so set the layout height to be 0dp before applying weight.